# More accurate nginx location matching

Tags: nginx

I have the following nginx rule

```
location /api {
    proxy_pass http://flask:5000/api;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

It will match the following path, which is what I'm expecting

```
http://localhost/api
http://localhost/api/
http://localhost/api/a
http://localhost/api?
http://localhost/api?name=value
```

However, it will also match the following, which I'm not expecting

```
http://localhost/apii
http://localhost/apiX
```

May I know how can I avoid from matching unwanted `http://localhost/apii` and `http://localhost/apiX` and `http://localhost/apiXX` and ...

Answer (score 1):

This requires two location blocks - one matching specifically `/api` and one for everything in the path `/api/`. In this way urls like `/apio` will not be captured.

Example:

```
location = /api {
    proxy_pass http://flask:5000/api;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
#Querystrings and /api, matches the first, any /api/* matches this one
location /api/ { 
    proxy_pass http://flask:5000/api;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Reference http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

Comment: Useful but this question is not looking for a generic answer. It should be one location block for `location = /api` and one for `location /api/`

Comment: Correct, but I have not tried to read querystrings with the = one. Does it match it?

Comment: the query string is not relevant to location blocks :)

Comment: Never actually tried with = . Thanks for the extra info, if you write the answer as an answer pretty sure will be given as the correct one (and I will upvote it :D )

Comment: Doesn't work. As, if `http://localhost/apiXX` will not match `location = /api`, it will still match `location /api`

Comment: It lacked a / at the end. Like this should work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use a regular expression. As the `proxy_pass` is not actually transforming the URI, the `uri` element can be safely removed.

```
location ~ ^/api($|/) {
    proxy_pass http://flask:5000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Note that regular expression location blocks are evaluated in order. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually really simple.

Just change `location /api {` to `location /api/ {`

Nginx will add a trailing slash to any request ending `/api` so there is no need to add a separate block for them. This block will behave as you expected your original one to.